# Can I sum multiple rows in a Pandas DataFrame on a single column? (and combine them into a single row in the dataframe)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have a Pandas DataFrame containing -

```
<pre>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th scope='column'>Fruit</ th>
            <th scope='column'>Address</ th>
            <th scope='column'>Quantity</ th>
        </ tr>
        <br>
        <tr>
            <td>Banana</ td>
            <td>Baker Street</ td>
            <td>10</ td>
        </ tr>
        <br>
        <tr>
            <td>Banana</ td>
            <td>Baker Street</ td>
            <td>20</ td>
        </ tr>
        <br>
        <tr>
            <td>Banana</ td>
            <td>Nautilus</ td>
            <td>10</ td>
        </ tr>
    </ table>
</ pre>
```

I would like a final dataframe that contains -

```
<pre>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th scope='column'>Fruit</ th>
            <th scope='column'>Address</ th>
            <th scope='column'>Quantity</ th>
        </ tr>
        <br>
        <tr>
            <td>Banana</ td>
            <td>Baker Street</ td>
            <td>30</ td>
        </ tr>
        <br>
        <tr>
            <td>Banana</ td>
            <td>Nautilus</ td>
            <td>10</ td>
        </ tr>
    </ table>
</ pre>
```

Is there a concise way to do this? Essentially, I would like to sum a table containing all-but-one common columns, on the final unique column.

Comment: You might want to check [groupBy](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html). However you will have to do a bit of data conversion as I don't think pandas support natively the XML format

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for groupby sum i.e

If you have a dataframe like

```
columns = ['Fruit','Address','Quality']
df = pd.DataFrame([['Banana','Baker Street',10],['Banana','Baker Street',20],['Banana','Nautilus',10]],columns = columns)
```

```
   Fruit       Address  Quality
0  Banana  Baker Street       10
1  Banana  Baker Street       20
2  Banana      Nautilus       10
```

Groupby sum with reset_index will give

```
new_df = df.groupby(['Fruit','Address'])['Quality'].sum().reset_index()
```

```
   Fruit       Address  Quality
0  Banana  Baker Street       30
1  Banana      Nautilus       10
```

You can also use `as_index = False` i.e

```
new_df = df.groupby(['Fruit','Address'],as_index=False)['Quality'].sum()
```

Hope it helps